# How to add digital signature in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In Magento2 I want to learn how can I add digital signatures for customer at checkout. What library should be used ?

I want to take digital signatures on customer agreement form.

I am currently using Magento CE 2.2.6

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @JancyAbraham not solution yet. But there is one extension on GitHub for Magento 1

Comment: @JancyAbraham https://github.com/vijays91/Magento-Digital-Signature for Magento 1. This is tested